# microsoft.insights/actionGroups ARM Template WebhookReceiver not working

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-rm-template

I'm using this template to deploy my AzureActionGroup :

```
 {
     "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
     "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
     "location": "Global",
     "name": "[variables('ActionGroupName')]",
     "properties": {
        "groupShortName": "Dispo",
        "enabled": true,
        "WebhookReceiver": [
           {
              "name": "Hook",
              "serviceUri": "http://requestb.in/1bq62iu1"
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

Everything ran without error. but when I go to the portal to watch my resource, I did not see any action WebHook instrumented.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "WebhookReceiver" with "WebhookReceivers", you should be good.